# Loop de repetição python

Tags: python, xml

Ola eu tenho um `for` que extrai dados de um arquivo XML e eu queria iterar uma contagem para mostrar como por exemplo assim:

```
1- O EAN é 7897748715180
2- O EAN é None
3- O EAN é 7897748729941
4- O EAN é 7897748729965
5- O EAN é 7897748729880
```

Meu codigo:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#Bibliotecas
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XML = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(XML)
root = tree.getroot()
print('\n')

ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    
    Contagem = 1
    print(f"{Contagem}- O EAN é {EAN}")
    Contagem = Contagem + 1
```

Eu estou fazendo a `Contagem +1` mais ele não esta somando, como fazer somar?

Comment: A definição da variável Contagem está dentro do for, sendo a cada loop definido como 1. Mova a linha Contagem = 1 para antes de iniciar o for, assim ele será incrementado a cada loop

Comment: é verdade @PauloC  eu mudei isso e funcionou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está atribuindo `1` ao valor a cada passo do seu laço de repetição, ou seja, o programa está somando corretamente, porém você está "zerando" o valor que foi somado a cada passo do laço.

Para resolver você pode criar a variável fora do laço, para isso basta mover a linha com o código `Contagem = 1` para alguma linha antes do `for`.

Ficariam assim:

```py
XML = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(XML)
root = tree.getroot()
print('\n')

Contagem = 1
ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    
    print(f"{Contagem}- O EAN é {EAN}")
    Contagem = Contagem + 1
```

Você também pode usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para criar um contador para cada iteração do `for`. Ex:

```py
xml = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(XML)
root = tree.getroot()
ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}

for cont, det in enumerate(root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns), start=1):
    ean = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    print(f"{cont}- O EAN é {EAN}")
```

Comment: Dum limão fez uma limonada.

Comment: Não entendi Augusto.

Comment: Duma pergunta que deveria ser fechada conseguiu criar uma boa resposta.

Comment: ah tá.. hahaha.. achei mais rápido responder do que procurar a duplicada